# Using Bootstrap + lint + TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, lint

I need to play around with some explicit JS functionality, in my example with Collapse:

```
const collapse = new bootstrap.Collapse(element, { toggle: false });
collapse.show();
```

To make this work, I have to following definition:

```
declare let bootstrap: any;
```

I get a `Unexpected any. Specify a different type.` lint error.

Is there an easy way to fix it, or just give it a suppress warnings with:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
```

Comment: You can fix it by giving it a proper type definition. Or is that what you are having trouble with?

Comment: Why don't you try installing [`bootstrap` types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/bootstrap)?

Comment: have you tried adding bootstrap type? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/bootstrap

Comment: Hah, this is exactly what I was searching for, thx! Pls post as an answer, will accept it :-)